# pandas string noise string canceling

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

Say I have a list of drinks:

```
drinks=['coke','water','milk','yoghourt']
```

And I have a pandas series containing some of the items mixed with other noisy strings

```
s = pd.Series(['cokeabc',Nan,Nan,'water coke',Nan,'milk and yoghourt','only water'])
```

My purpose is  filter out the noise first, fill in the missing value based on other column, and then get_dummies of the s column 
My try was:

```
buff=[]
for i in material:
    if df['drink'].str.contains(i):
        buff.append(i)
kvkl['drink']=' '.join(buff)
```

but df['drink'].str.contains(i) returns the whole column of bools

should I try apply()?

Comment: You could just create each column independently `pd.DataFrame({drink: s.str.contains(drink) * 1 for drink in drinks})`

Comment: @TedPetrou thank you, this is graceful. But I need to fill the missing value with groupby first, so I guess I still need to clean the 's' column first?

Comment: What is the exact output that you want? Can you edit your question to put that in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may easily make your code work by just adding `.any()` at the end of the code:

```
buff=[]
for i in material:
    if df['drink'].str.contains(i).any():
        buff.append(i)
kvkl['drink']=' '.join(buff)
```

This will check if any cell got `True` and deliver expected result.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figure it out

```
def drink_format(mtr):
    drinks=['coke','water','milk','yoghourt']
    buff=[]
    for i in drinks:
        if i in mtr:
            buff.append(i)

    return ' '.join(buff)

s=s.map(drink_format)
```